# ContentControl inside Grid does not resize correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I have a 3 column grid in which I have:

- a ContentControl, which has a content that does not fit and is clipped.
- a GridSplitter
- a third column with a min width

Here is the code :

```xml
<Window x:Class="TestGridWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" MinWidth="900" Width="900">
    <Grid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="Grid2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Panel1Col" Width="2000*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Panel2Col" Width="*" MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="5">
            <Rectangle Width="1800" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="Green"></Rectangle>
        </ContentControl>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="5"></GridSplitter>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="5"></Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With a fixed minimum width for the column, the first column shrinks a little when I reduce the window, but the Grid gets greater than the window and the third column is clipped.

Why does it do that? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Your `Grid` configuration :

- The 3rd column has star width and minimum width of 200.
- The 1st columns has 2000 star width. That means 2000 times wider
  than 3rd column which has minimum width 200.
- The window it self, has default width of only 900

Above configuration appears to be problematic. There won't be enough space to render all the columns properly (it is require window width of at least `200 + (2000*200) + 5`).

The end result, WPF renders this configuration as :

- The 1st column takes almost all `Grid`'s width.
- The 3rd column still rendered with 200 width, but only slightest part of it (1/2000 of width of 1st column) is inside the `Grid`, the rest is rendered outside the `Grid` at the right.

Rendered layout :

[image]

But how to fix it exactly, depends on what you are trying to achieve (the most makes sense is to reduce width of the 1st column). I hope that this explanation helps you decide better on how to fix the layout.

Comment: I know that 2000* is too big for the window. I set this width for my sample project because of the observed behaviour. My Grid is actually a `*/*` Width.  
 When I maximize the window, then reduce the right panel to the limit, then restore the window back to its original size, the right panel overflows...